# JSNI Wrapper object

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

Here is a common way to access JS methods:

```
public class JSNIHelper {
    public static native void errorNotify(String _title, String _text) /*-{
        $wnd.$.pnotify({
                                        title: _title,
                                        text: _text,
                                        type: 'error'
                                })
        }-*/; 
}
```

However is there a "object wrapper" on top of the JSNI to access Javascript in a more Java object way like:

```
JSNIWrapper().call("$").method("pnotify")
.set("title", title)
.set("text", text)
.set("type", type).now();
```

I'm not entirely sure as what is the best implementation, I'm not a JS expert. So  my question would be if there's any existing JSNI object wrapper that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) is a good complement for GWT, it has plenty of helpers which facilitates interact with javascript without writing jsni, etc.

In your case your code could be something like:

```
// Create a JSO and set the properties
Properties p =  Properties.create();
p.set("title", title);
p.set("text", text);
p.set("type", type);

// Get the JSO which has the function we want to call
JavaScriptObject $ = JsUtils.prop(window, "$");

// Call the JS method and get the result (null if the native
// js function returns void
Object ret = JsUtils.runJavascriptFunction($, "pnotify", p);
```

BTW: the chaining syntax you are proposing makes perfect sense, so you could propose this feature as an enhancement to the gquery Properties object. Something like:

```
$$().set("title", title).set("text", text).set("type", type).call(window, "$.pnotify");
```

Comment: Cool, I never thought that GwtQuery can do this, what is  $$?

Comment: GQuery.$$() is a static method to produce a JSO (Properties) object from a string, it does a good work fixing strings. Example: `Properties p = $$("name: manolo, admin: true, age: 14")` or `Properties p = $$("background: red; font-size: 5px")`

Comment: The $$ method needs a String parameter, your sample does not have?

Comment: Yes it needs a parameter, the example code is in the second block is not working code, just a proof of concept about how could be the API. The first block of code works though.

Comment: Oh sorry, i missed that one. Yah, this could be a enhancement to the GwtQuery library. So we don't have to go to the hoops of manually creating/calling different objects the the working example